# Configuring date command to meet my format

Tags: linux, bash, date, epoch

I have a date in YYYY.MM.DD HH:SS format (e.g. 2014.02.14 13:30). I'd like to convert it in seconds since epoch using the date command.

The command

date -d"2014.02.14 13:30" +%s

won't work, because of the dots separation.

Any Ideas?

Comment: What are the constraints? If you can do it in a bash script, so convert it and strip dots, and then convert to epoch.

Comment: Just a note: on freebsd there is `-f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you make the date format acceptable? Just replace dots with dashes:

```
$ date --date="`echo '2014.02.14 13:30' | sed 's/\./-/g'`" +%s
1392370200
```

Here I first change the format:

```
$ echo '2014.02.14 13:30' | sed 's/\./-/g'
2014-02-14 13:30
```

and then use the result as a parameter for `date`.

Note that the result depends on your timezone.

Comment: I should've mentioned that it acted piped in an awk command: awk  'BEGIN{getline}{command=("date --date=\""$1" "$2"\""); while (....

Comment: Then make the same replacement in `awk` using its `gsub` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
s='2014.02.14 13:30'
date -d "${s//./}"
Fri Feb 14 13:30:00 EST 2014
```

To get EPOCH value:

```
date -d "${s//./}" '+%s'
1392402600
```

Comment: why no of seconds differ?? in each ans??

Comment: ohh its due to EST AND IST got it :)

Answer (score 1):

using awk :

```
s=`echo "2014.02.14 13:30" |  awk '{gsub(/\./,"-",$0);print $0}'`
echo -d "$s"
date -d "$s" +%s
```

output:

```
Fri Feb 14 13:30:00 IST 2014
1392364800
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl: does not require you to munge the string

```
d="2014.02.14 13:30"
epoch_time=$(perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say Time::Piece->strptime(shift, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M")->epoch' "$d")
echo $epoch_time
```

```
1392384600
```

Timezone: Canada/Eastern

Comment: thanks, perl seems powerful, but one language at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally solved it using

awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{ gsub(/./," ",$1);gsub(/:/," ",$2); var=sprintf("%s %s 00",$1,$2);  print mktime(var), $3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }'  myfile  | less

so myfile:

2014.09.24,15:15,1.27921,1.27933,1.279,1.27924,234

became

1411582500 1.27921 1.27933 1.279 1.27924 234

:)